# replacing word with same word + added characters R

Tags: r

I have a regex `"^[0-9]\\.[0-9]|^§"`
Now i want to replace occurences and add something

Example
"foo" becomes "[[foo]]"

```
grep("^[0-9]\\.[0-9]|^§", Vector)
```

gives me all occurences unsure how to continue

Comment: Try `gsub` instead of grep

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sub`. If you put parentheses around your pattern, then you can refer to it in the replacement string with `\1`

For example, if your vector is like this:

```r
Vector <- c("2.9", "7.4", "A", "2.2")
```

And your regex is like this:

```r
grep("^[0-9]\\.[0-9]|^§", Vector) 
#> [1] 1 2 4
```

You can do

```
sub("(^[0-9]\\.[0-9]|^§)", "[[\\1]]", Vector) 
#> [1] "[[2.9]]" "[[7.4]]" "A"       "[[2.2]]"
```